# Force Tomcat 3.3 compiler to compile JSPs as Java 1.5

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a web application running on a (very old, I know, but I can't upgrade) Tomcat 3.3.2 Final servlet container and I had recently upgraded the VM that it's running on to Java 6.  This went smoothly so then I tried to use a Java 5 feature (specifically generics) in a JSP of the application, but it fails, not liking the syntax.  For what it's worth, I was putting something as simple as this:

```
java.util.List<String> users= new java.util.Vector<String>();
```

into a JSP and letting Jasper compile it, but I'm getting a compilation error.  I know that Tomcat is using the right JVM, but it seems to not be using the "-source 1.5" flag or equivalent.  Does anyone know how I can force my Tomcat to compile as Java 5?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the VM version you want to use in your servlet config file (web.xml):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.5</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.5</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: I put that code snippet into my application's WEB-INF/web.xml, just below the top-level element (ie as a direct child of `<web-app>`) but it still didn't help.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I haven't been able to find and corroborating evidence but I suspect Generics is only supported on newer versions of the Servlet spec. I believe the earliest version of the spec supporting Java 1.5 language features is Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0 which is supported by Tomcat 5.5.x. See [Apache Tomcat versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: I feared that might be the case.  Thanks for investigating.